# Unexpected NullReferenceException in F# Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, haskell, f#, mono, functional-programming

I'm trying to rewrite some Haskell algorithms in Richard Bird's *Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design* using F# and have run into a NullReferenceException that I don't understand.

The Haskell algorithm:

```
unmerges       :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
unmerges [x,y]  = [([x], [y]), ([y], [x])]
unmerges (x:xs) = [([x], xs), (xs, [x])] ++
                   concatMap (add x) (unmerges xs)
                   where add x (ys, zs) = [(x:ys, zs), (ys, x:zs)]
```

... which works as expected:

```
*Main> unmerges [1,2]
[([1],[2]),([2],[1])]
*Main> unmerges [1,2,3]
[([1],[2,3]),([2,3],[1]),([1,2],[3]),([2],[1,3]),([1,3],[2]),([3],[1,2])]
```

My F# version:

```ml
let concatMap f m = List.map (fun x -> f x) m |> List.concat

let rec unmerges (ints: 'a list) : ('a list * 'a list) list = 
    match ints with    
    | []      -> []
    | [x; y]  -> [([x], [y]); ([y], [x])]
    | x :: xs -> [([x], xs); (xs, [x])] @ 
                 (let add x (ys, zs) = [(x::ys, zs); (ys, x::zs)] in 
                  concatMap (add x) (unmerges xs))
```

... which works fine for matching the two element list but throws an error when matching the longer list pattern:

```ml
> unmerges [1;2];;

val it : (int list * int list) list = [([1], [2]); ([2], [1])]

> unmerges [1;2;3];;

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.op_Append[Tuple`2] (Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1 list1, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1 list2) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.concat[Tuple`2] (IEnumerable`1 l) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule.Concat[Tuple`2] (IEnumerable`1 lists) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSI_0055.concatMap[Tuple`2,Tuple`2] (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2 f, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1 m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSI_0055.unmerges[Int32] (Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1 ints) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at <StartupCode$FSI_0057>.$FSI_0057.main@ () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Stopped due to error
```

I tried defining `add` separately and that did not highlight any issues. I'd appreciate any insights into the exception and/or suggestions on how to debug.

Comment: Also, it occurs to me that this could be a Mono issue -- could someone possibly run the above in Visual F#?

Comment: Without knowing a lick of F#, I can only give you a sanity check. It appears to me that your algorithm matches the given Haskell algorithm.

Comment: @THK: FYI your F# port works on Windows as expected without problems.

Comment: Works fine for me with F# 3.1 and mono 4.0.3

Comment: Indeed, it works fine in Visual Studio 2015 FSI as well.

Comment: Works fine for me in Visual Studio 2012 (F# 3.0)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments! This appears to be an issue specific to my environment...

Comment: @THK you can omit `(ints: 'a list) : ('a list * 'a list) list` due to F# type inference

Comment: @THK what is your environment? F# version, Mono version, OS?

Comment: @RomanDibikhin F# 3.1, Mono 4.0.4, OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, running Xamarin Studio 5.9.6...

Comment: if it works for John using mono 4.0.3, it's weird that it doesn't for you, using a higher mono version; you should probably raise your issue in bugzilla: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: For the record -- it was indeed a Xamarin bug (details unclear, but it's resolved in the current alpha release, 5.10 and Mono 4.2.1).

Answer (score 1):

For the record—it was indeed a Xamarin bug (details unclear, but it's resolved in the current alpha release, 5.10 and Mono 4.2.1). – THK [Sep 22 at 2:23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621571/unexpected-nullreferenceexception-in-f-algorithm#comment53258166_32621571)